# VBA Runtime Error which works with breakpoint

Tags: html, vba

I am trying to extract data from a website and parse it using VBA. The code is working absolutely fine when stepping through the code however, when running it gives an 'Object Required' run-time error. Here is the code:

```
Function AuthToken()

Dim XMLHTTP
Dim result As String
Dim csrf As String
Dim token As Object
Dim objHTML As Object

Set objHTML = CreateObject("htmlfile")

Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")

With XMLHTTP
    .Open "GET", "some website", False
    .setRequestHeader "Cookie", cf
    .SEND
    result = .responseText
End With

With objHTML
    .Open
    .Write result
    .Close
    Set token = .getElementsByName("csrf-token")
End With

AuthToken = token(0).Content
AuthToken = Replace(Replace(Replace(AuthToken, "+", "%2B"), "/", "%2F"), "=", "%3D")

Set XMLHTTP = Nothing

End Function
```

The error is triggered by this line in the code:

```
AuthToken = token(0).Content
```

If I just click debug and resume, it works fine so I am really struggling to debug this. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried a wait after 2nd `End With` followed by `Set token = objHTML.getElementsByName("csrf-token")`. Remove the line `Set token = .getElementsByName("csrf-token")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, instead of

```
    result = .responseText
```

use

```
    If .status = 200 Then
        result = .responseText
    End If
```

Your code needs to be sure that URL has been loaded completely...4

If you place the next debugging line:

```
   Debug.Print token Is Nothing: Stop
```

immediately after

```
   Set token = .getElementsByName("csrf-token")
```

**Edited**:

If not a matter of `.status` not "OK", you can try to wait a little before reaching the problematic code line. Please call the next Sub, just before that line:

1. copy the next API on top of the module keeping the code (in the declarations area):

```
 Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetTickCount Lib “kernel32.dll” () As Long
```

2. Add the next waiting Sub:

```
Sub WaitALittle(Finish As Long) 
    Dim NowTick As Long,EndTick As Long
 
    EndTick = GetTickCount + (Finish * 1000)
     
    Do 
        NowTick = GetTickCount
        DoEvents 
    Loop Until NowTick >= EndTick 
End Sub
```

It can be simple called as `WaitALittle 2`. You may play a little with that 2 (time to wait)...

Comment: Please, what `.status = 200` means ?

Comment: @Waleed `.status` Returns the status-number of a request. 200: "OK", 403: "Forbidden", 404: "Not Found"

Comment: I tried the following instead (which should have achieved the same result as you suggested):

  `.setRequestHeader "Cookie", cf
    .SEND
    Do Until .Status = 200
    Loop
    result = .responseText`

Didn't work - I have the same issue.

The responsetext is always returned correctly as I can see it already parsed in the objHTML when deubugging the error, which is triggered later in the code

Comment: I have also added your suggested Debug.Print statement (after adding the do while loop) and it does stop the code but if i just resume from there it works fine. When i look at my locals window, the token object is absolutely not Nothing

Comment: @bml If after `Resume` it works, this means that `Debug.Print` line returned `False`... So, it is not a matter of not "OK" status. Anyhow, you cannot loop in that way, I am afraid. To be useful, that part should also contain something to make the code wait (inside the loop).  Anyhow, if not confidential, can you share the URL you try it on? I would like to test it. It may be a matter of necessary delay before that line. Or not... Without testing that specific URL I cannot understand what's happening...

Comment: I'm afraid it is confidential and internal (even if I shared you wouldn't be able able to access). Is there something you could suggest to put in the loop to wait? I tried application.wait but I think that pauses the entire module so doesn't really help. I even tried an empty loop that just increments a counter to 1000. Neither worked

Comment: @bml Try creating a loop (maybe in another Sub) and use an API. I cannot show it in my comment. I will edit the above answer and place such a waiting code. `DoEvents` is essential...

Comment: your update above solved the issue! Thank you very much for taking the time. Just for my education, is the sub you wrote just counting processor clock cycles?